# Prevent UIStackView from growing in height, without explicitly stating its height constraint

Tags: swift, uikit

I have a layout like this:
StackView(A) -> StackView(B) and View
StackView(B) can grow and shrink depending on its contents as well as View, but StackView(B) is just an additional view, so it should grow larger than it needs to be, but in cases when View is small, StackView(B) grows to fill of the space of the screen.
I tried calculating the height and setting it to a constraint, but StackView(B) can dynamically change, and after this its messes up. Also, I can just assign view.bottomAnchor to a view because all of this is happening in loadView and StackView(A) replaces viewController view with itself.
HugginPriority also doesn't seem to help here
EDIT: For some reason, when I remove all constraint from StackView(B) with removeConstraints(constraints) on init, calculating and setting the height constraint started to work. Maybe someone can explain why wasn't it working before?

Comment: *Probably* not a great idea to replace `viewController view` with a stack view. However, if you can explain why that's necessary, it's not at all clear what your sizing issue is. Show the code you're using and explain what's happening that you don't want. A couple images (what your want vs what you're getting) would be helpful.

Comment: @DonMag Sorry, can't really share it here because it's from work, but I can say that we doing it to display certain views on any screen of the app based on the configuration from the API. The issue happens when the main view wich is not the additional one, small, and then this additional view stretches to fill the rest of the screen

Comment: That doesn't tell us much about the issue. Are you **presenting** this as a modal controller? Are you adding it as a **subview**? Are you constraining it to the full height of the screen, and wondering why it *"stretches to fill the rest of the screen"*? If you want to get help, your really need to show us what's going on... otherwise we can only waste time guessing at what you're doing.

Comment: Just tried to do removeConstraints(constraints) of the StackViewB and it helped for some reason, I don't understand why

Comment: If an element is inside a stack, almost all the constraints will no work ( leading, top, bottom and trailing), only if the parent stack has the align on .center, otherwise the element will fill all the space. including stretch to fill all the parent height and width.

Comment: @Andrii - is this what you're trying to figure out? https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXWqk.gif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What could be happening is the StackA stretching it's content because of some constraint forcing it. If it's the case, you can add a UIView to stretch the remaining space.

Here is a solution that I implemented.

Basically, I stored the height constraint of stackB on a variable and changed the priority of it.

You can try this:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    private lazy var stackA: UIStackView = {
        let variable = UIStackView()
        variable.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        variable.axis = .vertical
        variable.spacing = 4
        return variable
    }()

    private lazy var someView: UIView = {
        let variable = UIView()
        variable.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        variable.backgroundColor = .blue
        return variable
    }()

    private lazy var stackB: UIStackView = {
        let variable = UIStackView()
        variable.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        variable.axis = .vertical
        return variable
    }()

    private lazy var label: UILabel = {
        let variable = UILabel()
        variable.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        variable.numberOfLines = 0
        variable.text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In eget sapien id risus malesuada vestibulum. Cras nunc turpis, tincidunt eget ex at, fringilla ultricies nibh. Fusce sollicitudin, risus id iaculis dictum, leo risus maximus nisl, ac porta tellus enim nec elit. Nunc dignissim tincidunt lacus, sed euismod orci feugiat ut. Aliquam non pellentesque elit, nec dictum magna. Nunc imperdiet, dui ut consequat bibendum, leo eros elementum urna, at faucibus augue quam in erat. Donec fringilla risus quis rhoncus consequat. Praesent ut lobortis sapien. Sed vulputate pretium massa, ac ultricies dolor feugiat nec. Phasellus a pretium elit. Donec vestibulum nisl id tortor convallis porta. Integer vel lorem augue. Phasellus magna nisi, hendrerit in arcu ut, aliquam pulvinar eros. Etiam suscipit id metus nec varius. Mauris pharetra urna non nunc feugiat, vel faucibus lectus venenatis. Sed vulputate velit scelerisque cursus sollicitudin.Vivamus egestas diam at velit porttitor rutrum. Ut ultrices nisl leo, nec"
        return variable
    }()

    var heightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(stackA)

        stackA.addArrangedSubview(stackB)
        stackA.addArrangedSubview(someView)
        stackB.addArrangedSubview(label)


        stackA.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 100).isActive = true
        stackA.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 4).isActive = true
        stackA.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -4).isActive = true
        stackA.heightAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualToConstant: 500).isActive = true

        someView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 400).isActive = true

        heightConstraint = stackB.heightAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualToConstant: 300)
        heightConstraint?.priority = .defaultHigh
        heightConstraint?.isActive = true
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, unfortunately I can't do it like this because stackB is dynamically resizing(reactive programming stuff) and if I set the height constraint, it won't be recalculated correctly after the change, even if I remove this constraint

Comment: but do you have a maximum size? if yes you can try use the constraint 'lessThanOrEqualToConstant' instead of  'equalToConstant'

Comment: just updated the code with the example

Comment: Then it will always default to the maximum constant, which is no really correct because it needs to have a certain height of the inner views + padding. I tried to calculate the height (which works correctly with every configuration change), but when I try to set it to the constant and remove this constraint after the configuration change to recalculate it, is doesn't calculate it correctly for some reason, only for smaller or the same size, as if the constraint is staying in place.